# Setting cache file path in PayPal API SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The whole process and the payment is working fine. The only thing that doesn't work is the cache after the completed money transfer:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in PayPal\Cache\AuthorizationCache::push() 
(Line 61 von /paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Cache/AuthorizationCache.php).
```

That is correct because PayPal should not write into the directory it suggests in AuthorizationCache.php:

```
abstract class AuthorizationCache
{
    public static $CACHE_PATH = '/../../../var/auth.cache';
```

Now I'm setting my apiContext - which is working fine as well (the log file will be written at the correct place where PayPal would be allowed to write to) but the cache file not. Currently I'm doing:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
  array(
    'mode' => $config['paypal']['mode'],
    'log.LogEnabled' => TRUE,
    'log.FileName' => 'sites/rest-api-sdk-php/var/PayPal.log',
    'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
    'validation.level' => 'log',
    'cache.enabled' => TRUE,
    'cache.FileName' => 'sites/rest-api-sdk-php/var/auth.cache',
  )
);
```

But that doesn't seem to be working - how can I set the cach file path?

Comment: It might have something to do with security context.
What happens when you do  ls -Z on those files?
Are the results different?
You may want to take a look at the chcon command.
Even if that gives you permission to write to the
file, you may want to double check and make sure you
want to write to the file in that location.

Comment: Can you manually just create an empty file with location auth.cache ? And set the permissions. It could be because PayPal SDK is not able to write/create a new file, probably because of some file permission issue (which is very common).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar problem resolved by setting following configuration in **config/paypal.php**

Add this line

> 'cache.FileName'            => storage_path() . '/logs/auth.cache',

```
return [
    'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID',''),
    'secret'    => env('PAYPAL_SECRET',''),
    'settings'  => [
        'mode'                      => env('PAYPAL_MODE','sandbox'),
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut'    => 1000,
        'log.LogEnabled'            => true,
        'cache.enabled'             => true,
        'log.FileName'              => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
        'cache.FileName'            => storage_path() . '/logs/auth.cache',
        'log.LogLevel'              => 'FINE'
    ]
];
```

FYI i'm using laravel 5.8.18
I hope this helps.